# Django MultiValueField - How to pass choices to ChoiceField?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-widget, django-models

I have a multivaluefield with a charfield and choicefield. I need to pass choices to the choicefield constructor, however when I try to pass it into my custom multivaluefield I get an error `__init__()` got an unexpected keyword argument 'choices'.

I know the rest of the code works because when I remove the choices keyword argument from `__init__` and super, the multivaluefield displays correctly but without any choices.

This is how I setup my custom multivaluefield:

```
class InputAndChoice(object):
    def __init__(self, text_val='', choice_val=''):
        self.text_val=text_val
        self.choice_val=choice_val

class InputAndChoiceWidget(widgets.MultiWidget):
    def __init__(self, attrs=None):
        widget = (widgets.TextInput(),
                  widgets.Select()
                 )
        super(InputAndChoiceWidget, self).__init__(widget, attrs=attrs)

    def decompress(self,value):
        if value:
            return [value.text_val, value.choice_val]
        return [None, None]


class InputAndChoiceField(forms.MultiValueField):
    widget = InputAndChoiceWidget

    def __init__(self, required=True, widget=None, label=None, initial=None,
                 help_text=None, choices=None):
        field = (
                 fields.CharField(),
                 fields.ChoiceField(choices=choices),
                 )
        super(InputAndChoiceField, self).__init__(fields=field, widget=widget, 
              label=label, initial=initial, help_text=help_text, choices=choices)
```

And I call it like so:

```
input_and_choice = InputAndChoiceField(choices=[(1,'first'),(2,'second')])
```

So how do I pass the choices to my ChoiceField field?

Edit:

I've tried stefanw's suggestion but still no luck. I've used logging.debug to print out the contents of InputAndChoiceField at the end of the init and self.fields[1].choices contains the correct values as per above however it doesnt display any choices in the browser.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this exact same problem and solved it like this:

```
class InputAndChoiceWidget(widgets.MultiWidget):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        myChoices = kwargs.pop("choices")
        widgets = (
            widgets.TextInput(),
            widgets.Select(choices=myChoices)
        )
        super(InputAndChoiceWidget, self).__init__(widgets,*args,**kwargs)

class InputAndChoiceField(forms.MultiValueField):
    widget = InputAndChoiceWidget

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        # you could also use some fn to return the choices;
        # the point is, they get set dynamically 
        myChoices = kwargs.pop("choices",[("default","default choice")])
        fields = (
            fields.CharField(),
            fields.ChoiceField(choices=myChoices),
        )
        super(InputAndChoiceField,self).__init__(fields,*args,**kwargs)
        # here's where the choices get set:
        self.widget = InputAndChoiceWidget(choices=myChoices)
```

Add a "choices" kwarg to the widget's constructor.  Then explicitly call the constructor after the field is created.

Comment: This example will cause `InputAndChoiceWidget.__init__()` to be called twice and because of the the kwars.pop you'll get a keyError exception. I got around this problem by removing the `widget = InputAndChoiceWidget` line

Answer (score 3):

[`ModelChoiceField` is technically a `ChoiceField`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.10.2/django/forms/models.py#L1128-L1231), but it doesn't actually use any of the `ChoiceField`'s implementations. So, here's how I use it.

```
class ChoiceInputMultiWidget(MultiWidget):
    """Kindly provide the choices dynamically"""
    def __init__(self, attrs=None):
        _widget = (
            Select(attrs=attrs),
            TextInput(attrs=attrs)
        )
        super().__init__(_widget, attrs)

class ModelChoiceInputField(MultiValueField):
    widget = ChoiceInputMultiWidget

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        _fields = (
            ModelChoiceField(queryset=Type.objects.all()),
            CharField()
        )
        super().__init__(_fields, *args, **kwargs)

        # Use the auto-generated widget.choices by the ModelChoiceField
        self.widget.widgets[0].choices = self.fields[0].widget.choices
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for, thanks! Also better then some answers above, as it does not require changes in the widget.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the source of `__init__` of `forms.MultiValueField`:

```
def __init__(self, fields=(), *args, **kwargs):
    super(MultiValueField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    # Set 'required' to False on the individual fields, because the
    # required validation will be handled by MultiValueField, not by those
    # individual fields.
    for f in fields:
        f.required = False
    self.fields = fields
```

So I would overwrite the `__init__` probably like this:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    choices = kwargs.pop("choices",[])
    super(InputAndChoiceField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields = (
        fields.CharField(),
        fields.ChoiceField(choices=choices),
    )
```

You might even want to do `super(MultiValueField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)` instead of `super(InputAndChoiceField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)` because you are setting the fields yourself instead of getting them via parameters.

Comment: I just tried this but I still get an empty choice field. I checked and the choices are passed correctly though. Any thoughts?

Comment: It looks like you should construct a 'fields' object before calling the MultiValueField constructor, and then pass that 'fields' value into the first parameter of the superclass's contructor.

Answer (score 1):

passing the choices in the widget solved this for me

```
class InputAndChoiceWidget(widgets.MultiWidget):
    def __init__(self, attrs=None):
        choices = [('a', 1), ('b', 2)]
        widget = (widgets.TextInput(),
                  widgets.Select(choices=choices)
                 )
        super(InputAndChoiceWidget, self).__init__(widget, attrs=attrs)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class HTML5DateInput(DateInput):

    input_type = 'date'


class CustomSelectRangeWidget(forms.MultiWidget):

    def __init__(self, attrs=None, choices = ()):
        widgets = (Select(attrs=attrs, choices=choices), HTML5DateInput(attrs=attrs), HTML5DateInput(attrs=attrs))
        super(CustomSelectRangeWidget, self).__init__(widgets, attrs)

    def decompress(self, value):
        if value:
            return [value.field, value.start, value.stop]
        return [None, None, None]

    def format_output(self, rendered_widgets):
        return '-'.join(rendered_widgets)

class CustomSelectRangeField(forms.MultiValueField):

    widget = CustomSelectRangeWidget

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if kwargs.has_key('choices') :
            choices = kwargs.pop('choices')
        else:
            choices = ()
        fields = (
            forms.ChoiceField(choices=choices),  #field with choices,
                                             # so that clean can be passed
            forms.DateField(),
            forms.DateField(),
            )
        super(CustomSelectRangeField, self).__init__(fields=fields, *args, **kwargs)
        #initialize widget with choices.
        self.widget = CustomSelectRangeWidget(choices=choices)

    def compress(self, data_list):
        if data_list:
           #check if datalist has 3 not null values
           if len([v for v in data_list if v not in [None, '']]) == 3:
               out_dict = {'field':data_list[0], 'start':data_list[1], 'stop':data_list[2]}
               return out_dict
       return None
```

Comment: This is solves my problem regarding choices in select field. It's a composition of 3 field, 1 Choice field, and other 2 are DateInput