# In Django, how do you save multiple form fields into a single model field as a list of values using a ModelForm?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Given:

```
from django.db import models
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    owners = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
```

where `owners` is a pipe-separated list of email addresses.

In the page, there are multiple `<input>` fields with the same `name`, so the server gets the values in an array.

The HTML code for the form was done by-hand and doesn't use built-in templates (such as `form.as_p`).

Can Django's `ModelForm`s handle something like this?

What is the proper location to handle the data transformation, both when retrieving the model (do I have to make a custom `models.Manager`?) and when saving it (which `save()` method do I override? the `Model`'s or the `ModelForm`'s)?

**--UPDATE FOR CLARIFICATION--**

In the database:

```
+-----+---------------------------+-----+
| ... |           owners          | ... |
+-----+---------------------------+-----+
| ... | "a@a.com|b@b.com|c@c.com" | ... |
+-----+---------------------------+-----+
```

The form:

```
<form ... >
    ...
    <input type="text" name="owners" />
    <input type="text" name="owners" />
    <input type="text" name="owners" />
    ...
</form>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`forms.MultiValueField`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/forms/fields/#multivaluefield) and [`forms.MultiWidget`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.MultiWidget). `MultiValueField` knows that your model's one field contains multiple discrete values and the `MultiWidget` widget knows how each discrete value should be presented. They'll handle creating unique names for your fields so that they can reconstruct the form from `POST` values and you won't have to override any form methods that provide implementation, i.e. you won't have to override `save()`.

As you can see, the official docs are a bit thin on the topic. I suggest you take a peek at the code to figure out how everything is wired and what gets called when, since your requirements are always going to need a unique solution, i.e: how many emails will the field contain? Exactly two, so I can specify two `CharField` widgets by hand, or is it going to be between 0-2, so I have to dynamically construct everything depending on the value passed? If you need a good example as a starting reference, check out [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617454/django-multivaluefield-how-to-pass-choices-to-choicefield) which contains a clean and easy to follow implementation.

Ideally, you'll want to have a `PipedEmailAddressesField` that extends `CharField` as your model's field, one that knows that it's storing piped email addresses. It should be able to construct it's own appropriate `MultiValueField` form field which should in turn construct it's own appropriate `MultiWidget` field.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer!  The way you said it, I'm kinda convinced that this is the correct answer.  Will try this out within the next few days to confirm it. :)

Comment: If it's not any bother, do you have any tips on how I should go about dynamically constructing the appropriate number of fields, say if I had no limit (or an incredibly large one)?

Comment: I did a partial solution.  I made a PipedEmailField that splits a pipe-separated string and runs validation on each token.  Didn't bother with the widget.  In my front-end, I just had a hidden input field where I dump a pipe-separated string from the values of multiple text fields using JavaScript, before form submission.  I'll accept this answer anyway, since it still proved to be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of saving a modelform in a view:
http://themorgue.org/blog/2008/05/14/django-and-modelform/
You can get the extra fields manually using `request.POST['fieldname']`
Hope this helped.