# Select Checkbox Values Already Saved on Editing in Form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

A user will be able to list his property and he/she will be able to edit the listing.

**The Problem**

On editing, all other fields will show data already saved by the user and only `amenities` field won't display 'values already selected'.

All the values of the `amenities` field are saved in a TextField and user can select multiple items via 'CheckboxSelectMultiple' widget.

Models

```
class Motel(models.Model):
    user= models.ForeignKey(User)
    name= models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Name')
    amenities= models.TextField()
```

I added 'checked' to the form field widget but it will only check all the items.

```
class MotelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    amenities = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=FACILITY_CHOICES, required= False, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'checked':'checked'}))
```

Views

```
@login_required
def edit_motel_details(request, motel_id, slug):
    if id:
        motel= Motel.objects.get(id=motel_id, slug=slug)
    else:
        motel= motel()
    motel_form= MotelForm(instance=motel)

    MotelImagesInlineFormSet= inlineformset_factory(Motel, MotelImages, fields=('image',))
    formset= MotelImagesInlineFormSet(instance=motel)

    if request.method== "POST":
        motel_form= MotelForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

    if id:
        motel_form= MotelForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=motel)

        formset= MotelImagesInlineFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=motel)

        if motel_form.is_valid():
            created_motel= motel_form.save(commit=False)
            formset=MotelImagesInlineFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=created_motel)

            if formset.is_valid():
                created_motel.save()
                formset.save()
                redirect_url=reverse('listed')
                return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url) 
 return render(request, 'm/m_edit.html', {'motel_form': motel_form,'formset':formset,})
```

I want to display already selected/saved items by the user in the 'edit form'. What am I missing?

Comment: I don't understand your approach. `TextField` is a blob of text, `MultipleChoiceField` is a list of check boxes. How can you assume that a list of check boxes would be saved into a blob of text?

Comment: It saved. Even if I put it in a CharField it will still save. I don't want to keep writing a model filled with 100's of items when I can do that with a line and save and retrieve. It saved like this [u'Wireless Internet', u'Air Condition', u'Swimming Pool', u'Television']. Django didn't explicitly state the 'only' data that can be saved in the field.

Comment: That's part of my point. You saved choices as a string, but there's no django documentation said that django is smart enough to recover a string back to a list of check boxes.

Comment: And that's why I'm here to seek for advice. Someone might have faced this before.

Comment: I did a simple research and found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335603/in-django-how-do-you-save-multiple-form-fields-into-a-single-model-field-as-a-l

Comment: Thanks. But it doesn't give a clue of getting through with this.

Answer (score 0):

In the `Meta` of your `MotelForm` add amenities in `fields`.

```
class MotelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    amenities = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=FACILITY_CHOICES, required=False, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())

    class Meta:
        model = Motel
        fields = ['name', 'amenities', ...]
```

Now when you will pass the instance it should load the values already selected.

Comment: I tried it but it's not not working. Still the same.

Comment: Are the fields apart from amenities like name loading after passing instance?

Comment: Yeah.. they all work perfectly except for the amenities field.